# How to access graph which is present in views.py file into html templates in django

Tags: python, django, matplotlib

I have a views.py file as follows

```
def showimage(request):
    # Construct the graph
    t = arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
    s = sin(2*pi*t)
    plot(t, s, linewidth=1.0)

    xlabel('time (s)')
    ylabel('voltage (mV)')
    title('About as simple as it gets, folks')
    grid(True)


    buffer = StringIO.StringIO()
    canvas = pylab.get_current_fig_manager().canvas
    canvas.draw()
    pilImage = PIL.Image.frombytes("RGB", canvas.get_width_height(), canvas.tostring_rgb())
    pilImage.save(buffer, "PNG")
    pylab.close()
```

Could you please help me to pass that graph into the html page?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you copied your code directly from https://www.eriksmistad.no/making-charts-and-outputing-them-as-images-to-the-browser-in-django/ but without the imports and definition.

You also left off the ending:

```
# Send buffer in a http response the the browser with the mime type image/png set
return HttpResponse(buffer.getvalue(), content_type="image/png")
```

But I wouldn't put this directly in my views.

Comment: Sir then where should I place this code .How could I pass it into html?